# SVG import: Embedded/linked images at the wrong place

Tags: inkscape, svg, scribus

I am using InkScape to draw an SVG and want to make it "printable" with that tutorial: https://www.klaasnotfound.com/2016/06/05/creating-cmyk-prepress-pdfs-with-inkscape-and-scribus/

Unfortunately, when I open the SVG in Scribus, the raster images that are included in the SVG are all at the wrong place (not slightly different, *way off*). This happens both when the images are linked and when they are embedded.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say what is going wrong here.

Scribus supports most SVG features that are translatable 1:1 to PDF commands.
Depending on the effects you have applied to your image, the SVG might or not completely / correctly load in Scribus.

What you can try?

- You could check if it works with the Scribus development version 1.5.4.
- You could try to produce a PDF from Inkscape and load that into Scribus.
- You could share the image (or a similar one that shows the issue) with us so that we can try.
- You should probably open a ticket in https://bugs.scribus.net and attach there the SVG (you can mark the ticket as private and only the developers will see it...)
- You could export a PNG from Inkscape and load that into Scribus.

Good luck!

a.l.e

p.s.: as you can read in the comments below, I've created a demo file showing the issue, created a ticket in the Scribus bug tracker and the bug has been fixed in a matter of a couple of hours... Thanks to the Scribus developper!

Comment: I can't give you the SVG, but it even happens when I create an empty page in InkScape, put a PNG with transparency onto it and save it. Nothing complicated ticked/checked/configured...

Comment: i could replicate and created a ticket for you: https://bugs.scribus.net/view.php?id=15409 . please review it... until it's fixed, you should be able to export a png from inkscape and import it in scribus... you just have to pick the resolution matching the print job.

Comment: Thank you, you were faster than me. :-) Looks right! I could repair my file by entering the coordinates manually (had to calculate a bit since the coordinate systems of Scribus and InkScape have different origins).

Comment: And Jean was also lightning fast! The bug is fixed in the development version. My demo SVG now loads correctly. Since you're only using Scribus for getting a print ready PDF, you can safely install it alongside to the stable version (if you have it). For Windows and OS X you can find snapshots in https://sourceforge.net/projects/scribus/files/scribus-svn/1.5.5.svn/ (it's not there yet...). For Linux there are [PPA snapshots](https://code.launchpad.net/~scribus/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) and other snapshots for other distributions .

Comment: Oh yes, I am very impressed of your/Jean's speed! I will try to try it at home where I can install whatever I want.